# remove a temporary environment variable and release memory in R

Tags: r, memory

I am working on a job in which a temporary Hash table is repeatedly used through a loop. The Hash table is represented by an environment variable in R. The problem is that as the loop proceeds the memory cost keeps rising no matter what method I used to delete the table (I tried `rm()` and `gc()` however neither was able to free the memory.) As a consequence I cannot accomplish an extraordinary long loop, say 10M cycles. It looks like a memory leak problem but I fail to find a solution elsewhere. I would like to ask what is the correct way to completely removing an environment variable and simultaneously releasing all memory it previously occupied. Thanks in advance for helping check the problem for me.

Here is a very simple example. I am using Windows 8 and R version 3.1.0.

```
> fun = function(){
    H = new.env()
    for(i in rnorm(100000)){
      H[[as.character(i)]] = rnorm(100)
    }
    rm(list=names(H), envir=H, inherits=FALSE)
    rm(H)
    gc()
  }
> 
> for(k in 1:5){
    print(k)
    fun()
    gc()
    print(memory.size(F))
  }
[1] 1
[1] 40.43
[1] 2
[1] 65.34
[1] 3
[1] 82.56
[1] 4
[1] 100.22
[1] 5
[1] 120.36
```

Comment: It appears that memory.size() is Windows specific. Porting this to my OS X box with object.size() I get the following, which does not show the growth you see: > for (k in 1:5){
+ print(k)
+ fun()
+ gc(0)
+ gc()
+ print(object.size(F))
+ }
[1] 1
48 bytes
[1] 2
48 bytes
[1] 3
48 bytes
[1] 4
48 bytes
[1] 5
48 bytes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am wondering if there is a substitute function for memory.size() in Mac that reveals current memory usage. object.size()  in my opinion returns the memory cost of a specific object rather than that of the whole work-space. So object.size(F) indicates the memory occupied by Boolean value 'FALSE'.

Comment: `memory.size()` gives the total memory usage. `object.size()` gives the memory for a specific object. You should be able to accomplish your goal via `rm(...); gc()` -- that is that you need to **first** remove the object, and **then** run garbage collection. If you need more help, refer to [lineprof](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Answer (score 6):

Environments in R are not a good choice for situations where the keys can vary a lot during the computation. The reason is that environments require keys to be symbols, and symbols are not garbage collected. So each run of your function is adding to the internal symbol table. Arranging for symbols to be garbage collected would be one possibility, though care would be needed since a lot of internals code assumes they are not. Another option would be to create better hash table support so environments don't have to try to serve this purpose for which they were not originally designed.

Comment: Thanks. It makes a lot of sense. Do you have any suggestion on how to implement a Hash table in R, or how to make symbols garbage collectible? I read through the manual of R package 'hash' and it also bases on environment objects. Thanks.

Comment: Making symbols garbage collectable would have to happen in the internals, so could not be available until the next x.y.0 release next year. Not promising it will make it into the next release but it might. Someone could write a package to provide a richer hash table data type, but would have to use some other technology than environments for now at least.

Comment: 3 years later, is there any update on this? It seems like `gctorture` is able to do this but in an ultra slow fashion.